# getApplication() in receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've wrote a receiver for an app involving SMS and it tests fine with a hard coded contact but now I want to use a phone number that is taken in from the user using a preference activity.

I have a SharedPrefernces object set up in my application object and from what I have read because of the difference in context between a service/activity and a receiver getApplication() cant be used and getApplicationContext() is only similar if its context your after.

Is there any way to get a reference to the contact in my receiver or should I completely change my approach? New to Java so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the receiver does receive the context, from there you can call the same shared preferences with:

[context.getSharedPreferences(String, int);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Hi Brudius sorry for delay getting back I have bad connection adding to the stress levels here. Hope Im asking this right but do i use the context given to the receiver via onReveive or do i use the context returned by getApplicationContext();

Comment: on this specific case (SharedPreferences) it doesn't matter. As long as you pass the same filename to the String argument. From both the receiver `context.getSharedPreference("mypref",0);` and the PreferenceActivity you call `getSharedPreference("mypref",0);` and they will be reading/writing the same data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it put me on the right track i used           String preferencesName = this.getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferencesName(); in my prefs activity then logged the string and used it in the call context.getSharedPreferences("preferencesName", 0); from my receiver. Thanks again